Water line shutoff is not turning
I am trying to shut off the water line that was hooked up to my refrigerator. It has a cock stop that is covered in greenish blue not sure what to call it mold like? I don't want to force it but it will not turn. My water bill was $200 last month and not watering grass.

Unless you use a lot of ice or drink a lot of water from the fridge, it should not use 200$.  Vinegar plus some salt might remove the stains/loosen the valve.

Why do you think turning off this valve will save water? Is the water line still hooked to the refrigerator? If yes where is the water going? If no, again where is the water going? $200 of water equates to thousands of gallons. I think you need to look elsewhere to find the reason for the excess usage.

"was going to" if you cannot turn the valve, perhaps you can cap the line ot crush the line closed (with locking pliers)?   the final solution will probably be replacing the bad valve.

Greenish blue sounds like oxidized copper, essentially rust. It's mostly harmless unless it eats really deep into the copper.

It's probably brass or copper that's corroded over time and frozen the valve.  Turn off the house supply and replace the valve.

A picture would help. If the valve has a packing nut then loosening it slightly (1/8 turn) may let you operate the valve. Retighten the packing nut afterward. Have some rags handy for the small amount of leakage that may result. Unless you have hand crafted artisanal water made from unicorn tears it is unlikely that this line is related to your billing issue. Some time when you haven't used any water for a while you might want to check exposed plumbing starting at the meter. Is there a pipe colder than the rest that would indicate water flowing when you don't expect it?

Copper does not rust. It creates greenish/blue patina that stops there.
The valve is stuck due to calc deposits (from water).
Due to that, it is recommended to operate all valves at least once per year.
With little bit of force it should work.
If not, take it out and perform maintenance. Get a new seal.
